# Pandas: identify is there any specific row within time range

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
data = {'event': [1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'team': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'], 'timeStamp': ['2023-07-23 14:57:13.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:14.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:15.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:16.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:20.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:13.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:18.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:23.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:23.357', '2023-07-23 14:57:25.357']}
```

I need to identify is there row with event "2" in 7 seconds after each row for each team.

Output should be like this

| event | team | timeStamp | is_2_in_7_sec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357 | TRUE |
| 1 | A | 2023-07-23 14:57:14.357 | TRUE |
| 3 | B | 2023-07-23 14:57:15.357 | FALSE |
| 2 | A | 2023-07-23 14:57:16.357 | FALSE |
| 3 | B | 2023-07-23 14:57:20.357 | FALSE |
| 1 | C | 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357 | TRUE |
| 2 | C | 2023-07-23 14:57:18.357 | FALSE |
| 3 | C | 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357 | FALSE |
| 4 | D | 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357 | FALSE |
| 5 | D | 2023-07-23 14:57:25.357 | FALSE |

In R it's quite easy, but in Python I'm stuck at this task.

Comment: Do you need test event=1?

Comment: Not only. Sorry, maybe I misinterpreted your question

Comment: Only solutions from me and accepted answer get different ouput for your data in table. What output is correct?

Comment: There are two outputs in the accepted answer. I need to exclude the row itself.

Comment: Then the first option with `shift` does that, the second one also considers the row itself

Comment: @jezrael you also offered useful method. Thank you

Comment: @Developera - Is possible check performance?

Comment: @jezrael checked, commented below your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rolling.html) [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html) after setting up a boolean column, then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to the original DataFrame:

```
out = (df.reset_index()
         .merge(df.assign(is_2_in_7_sec=df['event'].eq(2))[::-1]
                 .groupby(df['team'])
                 .rolling('7s', on='timeStamp')
                 ['is_2_in_7_sec'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).max()).eq(1)
                 .reset_index(), how='left'
               )
         .set_index('index').reindex(df.index)
      )
```

*NB. to exclude the row itself use a [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).*

Output:

```
   event team               timeStamp  is_2_in_7_sec
0      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
1      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:14.357           True
2      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:15.357          False
3      2    A 2023-07-23 14:57:16.357          False
4      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:20.357          False
5      1    C 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
6      2    C 2023-07-23 14:57:18.357          False
7      3    C 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
8      4    D 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
9      5    D 2023-07-23 14:57:25.357          False
```

If you want to consider the row itself as being equal to 2:

```
out = (df.reset_index()
         .merge(df.assign(is_2_in_7_sec=df['event'].eq(2))[::-1]
                 .groupby(df['team'])
                 .rolling('7s', on='timeStamp')
                 ['is_2_in_7_sec'].max().astype(bool)
                 .reset_index(), how='left'
               )
         .set_index('index').reindex(df.index)
      )
```

Output:

```
   event team               timeStamp  is_2_in_7_sec
0      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
1      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:14.357           True
2      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:15.357          False
3      2    A 2023-07-23 14:57:16.357           True
4      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:20.357          False
5      1    C 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
6      2    C 2023-07-23 14:57:18.357           True
7      3    C 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
8      4    D 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
9      5    D 2023-07-23 14:57:25.357          False
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems like a very good solution, but I'm getting an error when applying it to my large dataframe "ValueError: Each group within timeStamp must be monotonic. Sort the values in timeStamp first"

Comment: @Delopera You can add an initial `.sort_values(by='timeStamp')`

Comment: There was a small mistake both in the reproducible input and my answer, I fixed it.

Comment: @Delopera can you update the requirements? My solution should work with multiple 2s and can be adapted to work with multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

General solution with [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) - if need exclude row with `event=2`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'])

df['is_2_in_7_sec'] = (pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values(by='timeStamp').reset_index(), 
                                    df[df['event'].eq(2)].sort_values(by='timeStamp'),
                                    by='team', 
                                    on='timeStamp', 
                                    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7s'),
                                    allow_exact_matches=False,
                                    direction='forward')
                         .set_index('index')['event_y'].notna())

print (df)

   event team               timeStamp  is_2_in_7_sec
0      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
1      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:14.357           True
2      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:15.357          False
3      2    A 2023-07-23 14:57:16.357          False
4      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:20.357          False
5      1    C 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
6      2    C 2023-07-23 14:57:18.357          False
7      3    C 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
8      4    D 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
9      5    D 2023-07-23 14:57:25.357          False
```

If need include row with `event=2` remove `allow_exact_matches=False`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'])

df['is_2_in_7_sec'] = (pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values(by='timeStamp').reset_index(), 
                                    df[df['event'].eq(2)].sort_values(by='timeStamp'),
                                    by='team', 
                                    on='timeStamp', 
                                    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7s'),
                                    direction='forward')
                         .set_index('index')['event_y'].notna())

print (df)

   event team               timeStamp  is_2_in_7_sec
0      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
1      1    A 2023-07-23 14:57:14.357           True
2      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:15.357          False
3      2    A 2023-07-23 14:57:16.357           True
4      3    B 2023-07-23 14:57:20.357          False
5      1    C 2023-07-23 14:57:13.357           True
6      2    C 2023-07-23 14:57:18.357           True
7      3    C 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
8      4    D 2023-07-23 14:57:23.357          False
9      5    D 2023-07-23 14:57:25.357          False
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "'dict' object has no attribute 'sort_values'"

Comment: @Delopera - I think need `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: Sorry, my stupid mistake, I'm new in Python.

I've checked your first solution and for some reason got "True" only at first row.

Comment: @Delopera - Maybe reason is data in question in table and in `data = {...}` are different for `team` column

Comment: Ohh, yeah, you're right. I've updated the question. 

Your solution is also works fine. Thank you.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it works when event "2" occurs multiple times. But could you please help with right syntaxes if I want to use multiples events - not only "2"

Such way aren't working

df[df['event'].eq(1,2,3,4)].sort_values(by='timeStamp') also tried this

df[df['event'].eq(pd.Series([13,14,15,16]))].sort_values(by='timeStamp')

Comment: @Delopera - then use `df[df['event'].isin([1,2,3,4])]`, also if need test by `team` and `event` change `by='team', ` to `by=['team','event']`